# How do Hyperspace Jumps work?

Tags: physics, science-fiction

I ask this question because in a story I am creating, a Mercenary group is attempting a hyperspace jump in the midst of a battle. The problem is that they plan to use a bomb with a 8 second timer when it takes 10 seconds to complete the hyperspace jump. The hyperspace jump takes 10 seconds because the ship elongates itself (not visually or physically) leaving a bit of its physical portion behind before the 10 seconds finish.

My question is if my creative process is right because I am not sure if hyperspace jumps can work like this.

Comment: Take wiki with a pinch of salt but you can handwave a few things if you like, its your story https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperspace_%28science_fiction%29

Comment: "Hyperspace" is a complete fiction as far as we know so there is no "reality-check" that can be done on it.  The main thing you should attempt is to keep the rules consistent in how it is used AND try to think through the ramifications of how it works (e.g. Larry Niven's "Luck Gene" means the far future of his "Known Universe" gets really boring).

Comment: I think if you want a good answer to this, you will have to tell us more about how "hyperspace jumps" work in your universe. And of course, why your mercenaries wouldn't just set the timer for 12 seconds if the jump takes 10 seconds... As for your creative process, I'm afraid that's outside the scope of worldbuilding and as such off topic here, though once you have a bit more reputation (you need 20 rep for that) you can drop into [chat] which is much more free-form.

Comment: ic, so this is more on a creative design on my part rather than it being similar to other takes on hyperspace travel. KK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, hyperspace jumps can work however you want them to.

That being said you should be consistent in your story about how it works and stick with it.

Hyperspace is normally thought of as an adjacent set of dimensions/alternate universe, which is entered by altering our space in some manner that allows a space vessel to enter hyperspace.  It is usually referenced for traveling faster than light because the hyperspace has slightly different physical laws, no upper speed limit, or it maps differently onto our universe, i.e. travel a small distance in hyperspace equals a long distance in our space.  Because of the different physical laws in hyperspace, the transition can be accomplished however you want.  The transition between the spaces has been presented in several ways in fiction; the use of a gateways or surrounding the vessel with some kind of energy field being the most common.

This transition could easily take some set amount of time (it might be dependent on the size of the ship?) or require other conditions (speed of vessel, physical orientation, etc.) and could easily be used as a plot device as you mention in your question.

Wikipedia has a fairly good discussion of the hyperspace concept:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperspace_(science_fiction)